# try to make a gravity and jump function and platforms using picture boxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox

Hi i'm trying to make Donkey kong for a college project, we have to use c# and visual studio. I using picture boxes for my objects, so mario is a picture box so are the platforms. Im trying to make a gravity function but I can hcnage the location of mario. it keeps giving an error, Ive searched for help but theres nothing that helps me.

```
    bool right;
    bool left;
    int m_x, m_y, m_w, m_h;
    int gravity = 5;
    int speed = 5;


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        m_x = mario.Location.X;
        m_y = mario.Location.Y;
        m_w = mario.Size.Width;
        m_h = mario.Size.Height;

        Gravity();

        if (right == true){ mario.Left += speed; }
        if (left == true) { mario.Left -= speed; }
    }

    public void Gravity()
    {
        m_y += gravity;
        mario.Location.Y = m_y;      
    }
```

I get the error:

> Error 1   Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Location' because it is not a variable  C:\Users\Albert\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DonkeyKongPB\DonkeyKongPB\Form1.cs    56  13  DonkeyKongPB

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location(v=vs.110).aspx)? It's a property that gets or sets a `Point`

Comment: You can do `mario.Top = m_y` instead. Because `Location` returns a struct you need to do `Location = new Point(mario.Location.X, m_y);`.

Comment: THanks both of you that worked gill, Im not sure how point works i read the documentation and i didn't get it ;( any example of how setting points works would be great thanks.

Comment: Do I have to set this question as answered or what happens this is my first question??

Comment: You can accept an answer if there is one. I'll post one for completeness sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `mario.Top = m_y` instead to get the same effect since you're only modifying `y`.

---

Or, if you insist on doing it your way :

Because `Location` returns a `Point` struct you'd need to do:

```
Location = new Point(mario.Location.X, m_y);
```

Comment: Just for the record, the reason you can't modify just the Y value is that Point is a struct and not a class. Structs need all of their properties set when they are initialised and the values cannot be changed afterwards.